# Why does adding System.Web.WebPages.dll cause "Illegal characters in path." crash?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, web-config, url-routing

**Brief summary:**
When I add System.Web.WebPages.dll to bin folder of my app, .NET framework in my web app starts producing "Illegal characters in path." crash on requests like this:
http://qa.postjobfree.com/autocompleteskills/%22myskill

When I remove System.Web.WebPages.dll from bin folder - the error is gone.
Why does it happen?

Below are clarifying details in Q&A form.

**Q1: Why do you add System.Web.WebPages.dll to bin folder if System.Web.WebPages.dll is already part of .NET framework?**

Because I want to add MVC to my existing Web Forms application.
Newest version MVC requires System.Web.WebPages.dll (and 5 more DLLs) to be added to bin folder.

**Q2: Did you try setting relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping flag?**

Yes. Thanks to Scott Hanselman and multiple answers on Stack overflow, I added this configuration to my Web.Config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" maxRequestLength="8192" />
</system.web>
```

I added it several years ago and it fixed "Illegal characters in path." crash.

Now when I'm adding System.Web.WebPages.dll to web app bin folder - Hanselman's solution does not help anymore and I'm getting that crash again.
Here's possible hint to solving the problem: requestPathInvalidCharacters flags were not supported prior to .NET 4.0 (circa 2010).

**Q3: Does that "Illegal characters in path." crash  happen on all computers?**

No.
Unfortunately it crashes in production, but does not crash on my dev machine.

**Q4: What's the difference between your production machine and your dev machine?**

Production machine has Windows Server 2012 R2
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]

Development machine has Windows 7
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

Development machine has Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 installed.

Production only has .NET Framework 4.5.1 (the same as development).

But the most relevant difference between production and development machines is in System.Web.WebPages.dll version that is installed to GAC.
In my research I discovered 3 different versions of System.Web.WebPages.dll:

```
v1
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.dll
Size: 136,552 bytes
File version: 1.0.20105.407
Product version: 1.0.20105.407

v2
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.dll
Size: 204,480 bytes
File version: 2.0.20710.0
Product version: 2.0.20710.0

v3
C:\dennis\projects\ijs\PostJobFreeWeb\bin\System.Web.WebPages.dll
Size: 211,664 bytes
File version: 3.0.20129.0
Product version: 3.0.1-20129
```

I have v1 in GAC on my production machine.
I have v2 in GAC on my development machine.
I got v3 from MVC nuget package and put it into bin folder of my web app.

**Q5: Did you try putting different versions of DLLs into bin folder?**

Yes I did.

I found out that putting v1 into bin folder on production machine does NOT cause "Illegal characters in path." crash.

I found out that putting either v2 or v3 into bin folder causes "Illegal characters in path." crash.

So, basically, if dll in bin folder matches with dll in GAC - there is no problem.
But if there is a mismatch - then web project misbehaves.

I also tried to put v1 dll into bin folder on my development machine (dev machine has v2 in GAC). That did NOT cause any problems.

**Q6: Error Stack trace?**

```
Message: 
Illegal characters in path.
Type: System.ArgumentException
Stack:
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at System.Web.Compilation.DiskBuildResultCache.GetBuildResult(String cacheKey, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetBuildResultFromCacheInternal(String cacheKey, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper.ExistsInPrecompiledSite(String virtualPath)
   at System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryManager.Exists(String virtualPath)
   at System.Web.WebPages.DefaultDisplayMode.GetDisplayInfo(HttpContextBase httpContext, String virtualPath, Func`2 virtualPathExists)
   at System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.GetDisplayInfoForVirtualPath(String virtualPath, HttpContextBase httpContext, Func`2 virtualPathExists, IDisplayMode currentDisplayMode, Boolean requireConsistentDisplayMode)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.GetRouteLevelMatch(String pathValue, String[] supportedExtensions, Func`2 virtualPathExists, HttpContextBase context, DisplayModeProvider displayModeProvider)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.MatchRequest(String pathValue, String[] supportedExtensions, Func`2 virtualPathExists, HttpContextBase context, DisplayModeProvider displayModes)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.DoPostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: It happens to me also (but on dev environment) and it happens randomly on builds (cleaning and rebuilding solution a couple of times solve it also randomly)